# How to map an array of arrays in Mantle

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, github-mantle

Anybody got an idea of how to map this response to a mantle object?

I need to get these to an NSArray of custom classes. But the Mantle documentation has no mention on how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

```
 [
    [
        {
            "plu_id": "1744",
            "name": "With egg",
            "price": "2.00",
            "group": null
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "plu_id": "1745",
            "name": "add roast chicken",
            "price": "3.00",
            "group": "1"
        },
        {
            "plu_id": "1749",
            "name": "add beef",
            "price": "4.00",
            "group": "1"
        }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below snippet mentioned for an [identical issue](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/issues/434)

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)allRowsJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer transformerWithBlock:^id(NSArray *inSectionJSONArray) {
        NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:inSectionJSONArray.count];
        for( NSArray *section in inSectionJSONArray )
        {
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cardItemArray = [MTLJSONAdapter modelsOfClass:[CKMCardItem class] fromJSONArray:section error:&error];
            if( cardItemArray != nil )
            {
                [sectionArray addObject:cardItemArray];
            }
        }
        return sectionArray;
    }];
}
```